# Plot Timeseries ts object in R

Tags: r, plot, quantmod

How to plot ts object. month in x axis and monthly.returns in y axis for each year in same graph. please find the code that i am using.

stock<-"^GSPC"

getSymbols(stock,from = "2000-01-01",to = Sys.Date())

GSPC_pr<-monthlyReturn(GSPC)

GSPC_pr<-ts(GSPC_pr,frequency=12, start=c(2000,1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're using the `quantmod` package. You can plot it like this:

```
plot(as.xts(GSPC_pr), major.format = "%Y-%m")
```